# How do I get my font to show up on my WebSite?

Tags: html, css, fonts

so I am really new to programming have gotten way in over my head with this website stuff, but I cannot figure out why my text does not display in the custom font. It displays white italics text but I can't get the font to work. Thanks for any help!

````
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage</title>
        <style>
            @font-face
            {
                font-family: 'my font';
                src: url(C:\Users\theuser\Font\My Custom Font.woff2) format('woff2'),
                url(C:\Users\theuser\Font\My Custom Font.ttf) format('truetype'),
            }
            h2
            {
                font-family: 'my font';
                color: white;
                font-style: italic;
            }
        </style>
        <h2>Header text</h2>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="color:white;">Font testing</p>
        <body bgcolor="#000000">
    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: First of all, the path of the font: it should no be something that starts with C:\ since this will not work on linux/macOS, Instead you need to have a URL starting with ./ or / (this folder or root folder of http server respectively). I also highly recommend you not to use a font you have on your server but rather use a font from google fonts, which is really easy to use and has worked well for me.

Comment: Thank you! I will give the Google Fonts thing a shot but as of now my font seems to be working so I think I will just not tamper with it. Thanks anyways though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are on right track but you cannot directly import font from your local machine copy
My Custom Font from where ever you have it save and in your project directory create a folder name it
Fonts and then past your My Custom Font on the root of your project

ex:

```
myProject
| - js
| - img
| - Fonts <-- here
| - index.html
```

then inside your index.html you can import them into your project as

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src:  url('./Fonts/My Custom Font.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('./Fonts/My Custom Font.woff') format('woff');
}
```